# Django - Querysets - Eficient way to get totals

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have to get totals for diferent type of concepts (*Rem, NR, NROS, etc*) in the queryset **concepto_liq** and I'm doing one filter for each type (see the code below), is there a way to make it more efficent? Thank in advance!

```
tmp_value = concepto_liq.filter(tipo='Rem', empleado=empleado).aggregate(Sum('importe'))
remuneracion = 0 if not tmp_value['importe__sum'] else int(round(tmp_value['importe__sum'], 2) * 100)
tmp_value = concepto_liq.filter(tipo='NR', empleado=empleado).aggregate(Sum('importe'))
no_remunerativo = 0 if not tmp_value['importe__sum'] else int(round(tmp_value['importe__sum'], 2) * 100)
tmp_value = concepto_liq.filter(tipo='NROS', empleado=empleado).aggregate(Sum('importe'))
no_remunerativo_os = 0 if not tmp_value['importe__sum'] else int(round(tmp_value['importe__sum'], 2) * 100)
tmp_value = concepto_liq.filter(tipo='ApJb', empleado=empleado).aggregate(Sum('importe'))
aporte_jb = 0 if not tmp_value['importe__sum'] else int(round(tmp_value['importe__sum'], 2) * 100)
tmp_value = concepto_liq.filter(tipo='ApOS', empleado=empleado).aggregate(Sum('importe'))
aporte_os = 0 if not tmp_value['importe__sum'] else int(round(tmp_value['importe__sum'], 2) * 100)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do all filtering in the same query:

```
from django.db.models import Q

results = concepto_liq.filter(empleado=empleado).aggregate(
    remuneracion=Sum('importe', filter=Q(tipo='Rem')),
    no_remunerativo=Sum('importe', filter=Q(tipo='NR')),
    no_remunerativo_os=Sum('importe', filter=Q(tipo='NROS')),
    aporte_jb=Sum('importe', filter=Q(tipo='ApJb')),
    aporte_os=Sum('importe', filter=Q(tipo='ApOS')),
)
results = {k: 0 if v is None else int(v * 100) for k, v in result.items()}
```

This will count all items in the same query, and this work with one query, instead of five.